# Specify AppEngine version in Android application

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to access a non-default version of my AppEngine application using an Android app. For clearance, my default version is `1`, and my new version is `2`. Note that I cannot (yet) let version `2` be the default version.

From the docs:

> The  element contains the version identifier for the latest version of the app's code. The version identifier can contain lowercase letters, digits, and hyphens. It cannot begin with the prefix "ah-" and the names "default" and "latest" are reserved and cannot be used. AppCfg uses this version identifier when it uploads the application, telling App Engine to either create a new version of the app with the given identifier, or replace the version of the app with the given identifier if one already exists. You can test new versions of your app using a URL using "-dot-" as a subdomain separator in the URL, e.g. http://_version_id_-dot-_your_app_id_.appspot.com. You can select which version of the app your users see, the "default" version, using the Admin Console.

Unfortunately, Android applications do not use this url directly. The ids my app uses are:

```
final String PROJECT_NUMBER = "123456789012";
final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "123456789012-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345.apps.googleusercontent.com";
final String ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID;
```

The `PROJECT_NUMBER` is used for GCM registration, the `ANDROID_AUDIENCE` is used as follows:

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context, "server:client_id:" + Ids.ANDROID_AUDIENCE);
```

How can I get my Android application to communicate with version `2` of my AppEngine application?

Comment: It sounds like you're using one of the Google Eclipse Plugin tools to generate your Android code.  Are you building an "App Engine Connected" project?  I'm not too familiar with that, and it seems like Endpoints is the newer (replacement?) for it.  At least with Endpoints generated code, you can specify a 'hostname' where you can specify the appropriate version.  See here:https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed where I needed to look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dragonx provided a Python link, however, I'm using Java.

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations), it says you can define a `root` and a `version`. This is what I've done to make this work:

- Add `version` and `root` to my endpoint class:

.

```
@Api(version = "2", root="https://2-dot-my_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api", name = "deviceinfoendpoint", clientIds = (...) )
public class DeviceInfoEndpoint {
```

- Generate the Client Library
- Deploy to AppEngine.

Now all calls made through my `DeviceInfoEndpoint` class are sent to version `2` of my AppEngine application.